# The bibliography does not appear on the pdf document

Tags: biblatex

I am using the default setting on Texmaker except at quick build option I am using pdflatex + biblatex + pdflatex(2x) + view pdf. It prints the references but the bibliography section does not appear.

If I use online overleaf editor I get no errors and it prints the bibliography.

The online difference is that at online editor I get refernces like [numbers like 1,2,3], and when I am using Texmaker it appears [refernce name]

The biblatex packages that I am using:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\BiblatexHungarianWarningOff
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
```

The Texmaker output message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 21.2) The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file main.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux (There were 3 error messages)

bibtex: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.

Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: Bibtex is wrong, you need biber, adapt the profile.

Comment: Tell TeXmaker to run Biber for you (and not BibTeX). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for more details.